# Excel - Open Pdf in WebBrowser with a textbox value

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

What I want to do is to be able to open a PDF file with the respetive name as the value of a textbox.

I currently have the following code to open a PDF file on the WebBrowser, but I want to be able to open a PDF depending of the value of the Textbox.

```
Me.WebBrowser1.Navigate "about:blank"
Me.WebBrowser1.Document.write "<HTML><Body><embed src=""C:pathwaytopdf.pdf"" width=""100%"" height=""100%"" /></Body></HTML>"
```

thank you.
[image]

Comment: All the files with the respective name will be put on a specific folder.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After all this was extremely easy with the following code:

```
WebBrowser1.Navigate ("C:\filepath" & "\" & TextBox1.Value & ".pdf")
```

Disregard this one.